# adding variables from google spreadsheet to html template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialog, template-engine

I am trying to push variables from a spreadsheet into some fields of a html template, other fields of the template will remain blank for the user to fill in. the user can then click submit to put the data back into the spreadsheet.

I have written the code below which successfully opens a user interface and adds a new row. but I would like the first name to be a variable taken from data within the spreadsheet

here is my code so far....

```
function onOpen() {
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
  .createMenu('Dialog')
  .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
  .addToUi();
}
function openDialog() {
 var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('INDEX')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}
function getValuesFromForm(form){
 var firstName = form.firstName,
  lastName = form.lastName,
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 sheet.appendRow([firstName, lastName]);
}
```

here is my html

```
<b>Add Row To Spreadsheet</b><br />
    <form>
    First name: <input id= "firstname" name="firstName" type="text" />
    Last name: <input id="lastname" name="lastName" type="text" />
   <input onclick="formSubmit()" type="button" value="Add Row" />
   <input onclick="google.script.host.close()" type="button" value="Exit" />
   </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function formSubmit() {
        google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(document.forms[0]);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you are not actually using templated html to create the output. You're going to want to take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) link for more information on templated html in apps scripts.

The main difference in your code will be that instead of using `.createHtmlOutputFromFile()` to create your output, you will need to use `.createTemplateFromFile()` to create a template, then push the variables to the template before evaluating.
So your Apps Script code would look something like this

```js
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('INDEX')
html.sheetValue = valueToBeUsed //This is whatever value you want to push to html
SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
 .showModalDialog(html.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME), 'Dialog title');
```

To use the value in your html, you need to use something called scriplets, which allow you to use apps script code in your html file.
To do this, wherever you would like to insert the variable you pushed to the html, type `<?= valueToBeUsed ?>`.
Of course, substituting `valuToBeUsed` for your variable in both cases.

Comment: thanks very much for your response, after a lot of thinking i managed to work it out, #stilllearning

Comment: Glad you could figure it out!  There is tons of silly little gotchas with google apps script, you'll get the hang of it soon! #alwayslearning